# need regular expression in jquery for number i.e. (0213-6995688)

Tags: jquery, regex

I need regular expresion for number upto 12 in length with ( - ) after 4 digits and starting with zero only kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
/0\d{3}\-\d{7}/
```

this will match for exactly 12 length

read documentations and learn regex , its very useful

according to the comment if you want a regex which allows `upto` 12 , then

```
/0\d{3}\-\d{1,7}/
```

Comment: and why is this downvote for ?

Comment: According to the OPs text, `0123-4` would also be valid input, but your regex doesn't allow that. (Downvote not from me, BTW).